# does not create xcode project file in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I run create-react-native-app AwesomeProject, no XCode project gets generated.

Just this files created :

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 4):

It's a normal result. `create-react-native-app` is not supposed to create ios and android folders. It is to be used with Expo client.

If you want to have Xcode files, use `react-native-cli`:

On the top of [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), click "Building Projects with Native Code" instead of "Quick Start".

Answer (score 3):

run `npm run eject` at the root of your project folder, it will create ios and android folders.

This will start the process of "ejecting" from Create React Native App's build scripts. You'll be asked a couple of questions about how you'd like to build your project.